# How to communicate between apps in profile owner and device in android lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, mdm, device-policy-manager

I am developing a DPM application.
After creating a provising profile, I can see two copy of my application.
What I want is, all the server communication should be done my device owner app and this app should communicate all related data to profile owner app.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to make the non-managed app communicating with the profile owner app?